# How can a named route have URL parameters in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm building a web-app which needs to have a route that gets a post ID and then it will fetch the post using the ID.

How can I have URL arguments let's say `/post/:id` so id is the argument

My app looks like that currently:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // title: "Paste",
      initialRoute: "/",
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          primaryColor: Colors.blue
      ),
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => HomePage(),
        "/post": (context) => PastieRoute()
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
This is what I tried according to @BloodLoss and for some reason I don't get anything to the console when accessing `localhost:8080/post?id=123`

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => HomePage(),
        "/post": (context) => PastieRoute()
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == "/post") {
          print(settings.arguments); // Doesn't fire :(

          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              // TODO
            }
          );
        }
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://flutteragency.com/pass-parameters-to-web-app/

Answer (score 21):

### tl;dr

```
//in your example: settings.name = "/post?id=123"
final settingsUri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
//settingsUri.queryParameters is a map of all the query keys and values
final postID = settingsUri.queryParameters['id'];
print(postID); //will print "123"
```

### Drilldown

In a perfect world you would access `queryParameters` with `Uri.base.queryParameters` because:

[Uri.base](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Uri/base.html)

> Returns the natural base URI for the current platform.
>   When running in a browser this is the current URL of the current page (from window.location.href).
>   When not running in a browser this is the file URI referencing the current working directory.

But currently there is an issue in flutter where you have `#/` in your path which messes the `Uri.base` interpretation of the Uri.
Follow the [issue #33245](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33245) until this matter is addressed and you will be able to use `Uri.base.queryParameters`

Comment: "Get.rootDelegate.parameters" gor nav2 or navigation 2.0 with Getx

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy to get rid of the #

Comment: I am trying your answer out but myURL/anything just goes to a 404.... only the root myURL works. How do i get to execute the onGenerateROute code?

Answer (score 3):

please follow this link further information https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

on your `MaterialApp`

```
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    // If you push the PassArguments route
    if (settings.name == PassArgumentsScreen.routeName) {
      // Cast the arguments to the correct type: ScreenArguments.
      final ScreenArguments args = settings.arguments;

      // Then, extract the required data from the arguments and
      // pass the data to the correct screen.
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return PassArgumentsScreen(
            title: args.title,
            message: args.message,
          );
        },
```

or you can nativate like web using this plugin [fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro)

Comment: This looks more like query arguments type of things, which is not what I would expect from something like `/post/:id` since id is just a value and not  `key-value`

Comment: according to my flutter knowledge, you can't do it like this

Comment: Oh alright, I hope it will become a thing for flutter_web.

Comment: Can you please check my question edit? and about Fluro. I don't think it's supported for Flutter web? as there's no mentioning about it

Comment: @TheOnlyArtz  does Fluro support Flutter web? If not any other options available?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. You can edit it as per your requirements. If you want to use ?q= then use the split by or regex accordingly

Here is the example of both passing in argument as well as passing in url as /topic/:id

```
  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  List<String> pathComponents = settings.name.split('/');
  final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
  switch ("/"+pathComponents[1]) {
    case shareTopicView:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TopicPageLayout(topicID: pathComponents[2]));
    case internalTopicView:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TopicPageLayout(topicID: arguments['topicID']));
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingPage());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Flutter, and I found a quirky workaround,...

```
import 'dart:html';

String itemID;

//My url looks like this,... http://localhost:57887/#item_screen/12345
//Counted 13 characters for '#item_screen/' then got the substring as below 

 itemID = window.location.hash.substring(13);
 print(itemID) //12345
```

Not very sophisticated, but worked :-D

Answer (score 2):

Add [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular) to your flutter web project.

current version: `flutter_modular: ^3.1.1`

Read dynamic routes section in: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#dynamic-routes

Example for the URL `/post?id=123`

1. Create your main widget with a MaterialApp and call the ´´´MaterialApp().modular()´´´ method.

   ```
    //  app_widget.dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';

    class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: "/",
        ).modular();
      }
    }
   ```
2. Create your project module file extending Module:

   ```
    // app_module.dart
    class AppModule extends Module {
      @override
      final List<Bind> binds = [];

      @override
      final List<ModularRoute> routes = [
          ChildRoute('/', child: (_, __) => HomePage()),
          ChildRoute('/post', child: (_, args) => PostPage(id: args.queryParams['id'])),
     ];
    }
   ```

3.In main.dart file, wrap the main module in ModularApp to initialize it with Modular:

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';

import 'app/app_module.dart';

void main() => runApp(ModularApp(module: AppModule(), child: AppWidget()));
```

Comment: flutter_modular works badly with things like drawers, and swipe back navigation and doesn't actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution:

First, kind of seperate, I have an abstract class, `AppRoutes`, which is just a collection of string-routes, that way they're easily maintainable and switchable.

```
abstract class AppRoutes {    
  static const String guestGetMember = "/guest_getMember";
  ...

  static render(String url, {Map<String, dynamic>? params}) {
    return Uri(path: url, queryParameters: params ?? {}).toString();
  }
}
```

Now for the code:

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(settings.name ?? "");
  Map<String, dynamic> params = {};
  // Convert numeric values to numbers. This is optional.
  // You can instead `int.parse` where needed.
  uri.queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
    params[key] = int.tryParse(value) ?? value;
  });
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> arguments = (settings.arguments ?? {}) as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    switch (uri.path) {
      case AppRoutes.guestGetMember:
        return CardGuestViewProfile(memberID: params['memberID']!);
      case AppRoutes...:
        return...;
      default:
        return AppScreen();
    }

    // Navigator routes update web URLs by default,
    // while `onGeneratedRoute` does not. That last
    // line forces it to. The whole of using url
    // variables for me was so that certainly URLs
    // were easily copiable for sharing.
  }, settings: (RouteSettings(name: settings.name)));
}
```

And then I call it with

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,
  AppRoutes.render(AppRoutes.guestGetMember,
    params: {'memberID': memberID.toString()}),
  arguments: {}));
```

`params` will be easily visible to web-users because it's a URL variable, while `arguments` will not be. This of course doesn't mean that `arguments` is by any means secure, it just means that non-essential information can be passed through this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that uses the 'default' route as my main route.

I did this because it seems to be the only way that Flutter will allow me to open a URL with an ID in it, that doesn't return a 404.

E.g. Flutter does not seem to respect the '?' separator. So a URL with an ID in it, is read by flutter as an unknown URL. E.g. site.com/invoice?id=999 will return a 404, even in /invoice is set up as route.

My goal: I have a 1-page web app that simply displays a single invoice at a time, which corresponds to the ID in the URL.

My URL

[app.com/#/xLZppqzSiSxaFu4PB7Ui](https://www.app.com/#/xLZppqzSiSxaFu4PB7Ui)

The number at the end of the URL is a FireStore Doc ID.

Here's the code in MyApp:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          List<String> pathComponents = settings.name.split('/');
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Invoice(),
              );
              break;
            default:
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Invoice(
                  arguments: pathComponents.last,
                ),
              );
          }
        },
```

This sends 'xLZppqzSiSxaFu4PB7Ui' to the 'Invoice' widget.

Answer (score 1):

And here is another way to do it:

My url pattern: [www.app.com/#/xLZppqzSiSxaFu4PB7Ui](https://www.app.com/#/xLZppqzSiSxaFu4PB7Ui)

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          List<String> pathComponents = settings.name.split('/');
          if (pathComponents[1] == 'invoice') {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return Invoice(arguments: pathComponents.last);
              },
            );
          } else
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return LandingPage();
              },
            );
          ;
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try onGenerateRoute with below sample

```
  final info = settings.arguments as Mediainfo?;

    settings = settings.copyWith(
        name: settings.name! + "?info=" + info!.name, arguments: info);
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => MediaDetails(info: info), settings: settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

This same question I faced while I tried Flutter Web, I tried angular type routing for the path and queries param. It is working perfectly but there is not provided child routing. For the path parsing use `path_to_regexp` and use URI for the `queryParams`.

`pubspec.yaml`

```
path_to_regexp: ^0.4.0
```

`activated_routes.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_to_regexp/path_to_regexp.dart';

typedef RoutingParameters = Route Function(
  RouteSettings settings,
  Map<String, dynamic> param,
);

class _RoutingParametersHandler {
  final String path;
  final RoutingParameters routingParameters;

  _RoutingParametersHandler(this.path, this.routingParameters);
}

class ActivatedRoutes {
  static final ActivatedRoutes _instance = ActivatedRoutes._();
  ActivatedRoutes._();
  static ActivatedRoutes get instance => _instance;

  final List<_RoutingParametersHandler> _routingList = [];

  void addRoute(String path, RoutingParameters routingParameters) {
    _routingList.add(_RoutingParametersHandler(path, routingParameters));
  }

  Route? onGeneratedRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(settings.name ?? '');
    _RoutingParametersHandler? routingHandler;
    Map<String, dynamic> param = {};

    for (var element in _routingList) {
      final parameters = <String>[];
      final tokens = parse(element.path, parameters: parameters);
      final regExp = tokensToRegExp(tokens);
      if (regExp.hasMatch(uri.path)) {
        routingHandler = element;
        final match = regExp.matchAsPrefix(uri.path);
        Map<String, String> pathParamMap = extract(parameters, match!);
        pathParamMap.forEach((key, value) {
          param[key] = value;
        });
      }
    }

    if (uri.queryParameters.isNotEmpty) {
      uri.queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
        param[key] = value;
      });
    }

    if (routingHandler != null) {
      return routingHandler.routingParameters(settings, param);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

`routes.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Routes {
  static setUpRoute() {
    ActivatedRoutes.instance.addRoute('/', (settings, params) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) => const LoginPage(),
      );
    });

    ActivatedRoutes.instance.addRoute('/dashboard/:id', (settings, params) {
      print(params)
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) => const DashboardPage(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  useWebConfig();
  Routes.setUpRoute();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) =>
          ActivatedRoutes.instance.onGeneratedRoute(settings),
    );
  }
}
```

`routing_ext.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension ContextNavigatorExtension on BuildContext {
  pushNamed(
    String path, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
    Object? arguments,
  }) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      this,
      Uri(
        path: path,
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
      ).toString(),
      arguments: arguments,
    );
  }
}
```

for the navigation use below code:

```
context.pushNamed(
    '/dashboard/59',
    queryParameters: {
      'data': 'Hello!',
    },
);
```

Output:

http://localhost:60031/dashboard/59?data=Hello!

{id: 59, data: Hello!}