# How to keep the Url parameters in Flutter web route path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, url-parameters, dart-html

I am building a flutter web app which requires a url parameter in the start.

Currently it needs a parameter like `http://localhost:49844/?id=105897`

But after the app catches the url it disappears (like `http://localhost:49844/#/`) from the web address bar causing the application to fail on refresh of the site. Is there a way to keep the parameter once in the Url path?

In my code I use code below to get the parameter value from the Url

```
String appUrl = Uri.base.queryParameters["id"].toString();
```

Also, I use `home:` instead of routes as I only have a single page to be displayed.

Comment: did you found the ans?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try `initialRoute` and `onGenerateRoute` instead of `home`

This is just sample code, you can check [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) for a more precise way. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552885/how-can-a-named-route-have-url-parameters-in-flutter-web).

```dart
  MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/?id=105897',
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
      int id = int.parse(uri.queryParameters['id']);
      return const Home(id);
    },
  );
```

Comment: What to do for unnamed routes ?